# Angular - RxJS - Return observable when a value is true

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-observable

I have this function. I want these lines:

```
this.setHeaders(url);
return this.request(url, options);
```

to execute when `this.refreshTokenService.wait === false`.

```
private catchErrors(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) {

    return (res: Response) => {
        if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {

            if (this.refreshTokenService.wait === false) {
                console.log('FIRST');
                this.refreshTokenService.wait = true;
                return this.refreshTokenService.refreshToken(localStorage.getItem('JWToken'))
                    .flatMap((result: any) => {
                        // if got new access token - retry request
                        localStorage.setItem('JWToken', JSON.parse(result._body).token);
                        this.setHeaders(url);
                        this.refreshTokenService.wait = false;
                        return this.request(url, options);
                    })
            } else {
                // TODO here
                this.setHeaders(url);
                return this.request(url, options);

            }
        } else {
            Observable.throw(res);
        }
    };
}
```

But the function wants only to return observable or promise to run smoothly.

Thank you

```
request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

    if (typeof url === 'string') {
        if (!options) {
            options = {headers: new Headers()};
        }
        this.setHeaders(options);
    } else {
        this.setHeaders(url);
    }

    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchErrors(url, options));
}
```

Comment: What does this.request(url,options) return?

Comment: Also, Can you please specify what is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: It is not an output error. Until I get the new token, it tries continiously to run the following requests.

I want first to take the new token, and after that to continue with all the other requests.

Comment: I think that this function returns an observable. Anyway, I want to return this Function when this.refreshTokenService.wait === false

Comment: I try this, but didn't work

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        resolve( this.request(url, options) );
                      });

Answer (score 0):

In your last else statement, you need to return the observable. 
So instead of

```
else {
        Observable.throw(res);
    }
```

you need to do:

```
else {
        return Observable.throw(res);
    }
```

Comment: i don't have problem with this line